# Hazelcast Complex Object Model in Cache

Tags: persistence, hazelcast, object-graph

I am looking to put a complex model into Hazelcast to use it as the data tier of an application with MapStore implementations rendering the actual objects to the database. So for example, lets say we have the following noxiously common model where I have stripped out getters and setters for brevity:

```
class Customer {
  public int id;
  public String name;
  public Address address;
}

class Address {
  public int id;
  public String street;
  public string city;
  public String state;
  public String zip;
}

class InterestGroup {
  public int id;
  public String name;
  public List<Customer> customers;
}
```

This is a model that I want to store in the database but I also want to map into Hazelcast. Furthermore lets say that I want customers to share addresses such that if the address changes for one, it will change for all customers with that address.

I can write MapStore classes to read this information out of the database and even give each object a primary key to use as a map key. What I am having trouble with is setting up navigation within the map between entities. Lets say I obtain a customer and want to navigate to the address of that customer and then get all customers that use that address.

If I load customers and addresses into a map, I dont want to embed all customers in an address nor do I want to embed the address in each customer. I want to navigate transparrently from the customer to the address. Is there a means by which I could do this in hazelcast without breaking the dynamics of a nested object but while allowing addresses to live in another map? The situation is similar for interest groups. If I embed all customers in an interest group then I am duplicating data all over especially if the customer is in several interest groups.

To accomplish this without duplication all over do I have to compromise the object structure of my entities?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to build the address_key for the address Hazelcast map you can implement HazecastInstanceAware to your model classes and build some kind of "lazy fetch" using getters to retrieve the address. Does that make sense to you? :)